# Pandas groupby on selected rows and columns only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

For the following dataframe, I need to select rows from `2017-03` to `2017-05` for each `type`, then grouby `type` and calculate means for `v2` and `v3`:

```
  type     date  v1  v2  v3
0    a  2017-01   8  16  32
1    a  2017-02   3   6  12
2    a  2017-03   6  12  24
3    a  2017-04   6  12  24
4    a  2017-05   5  10  20
5    b  2017-01   4   8  16
6    b  2017-02   3   6  12
7    b  2017-03   5  10  20
8    b  2017-04   9  18  36
9    b  2017-05   4   8  16
```

The sliced dataframe will look like this:

```
  type     date  v2  v3
0    a  2017-03  12  24
1    a  2017-04  12  24
2    a  2017-05  10  20
3    b  2017-03  10  20
4    b  2017-04  18  36
5    b  2017-05   8  16
```

My expected will look like this:

```
  type     v2     v3
0    a  11.33  22.67
1    b  12.00  24.00
```

How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You described in words something that would look like this:

```
(df.loc[df['date'].between('2017-03', '2017-05')]
   .drop(['v1'], 1) 
   .groupby('type', as_index=False)
   .mean())

  type         v2         v3
0    a  11.333333  22.666667
1    b  12.000000  24.000000
```

P.S: "date" does not need to be treated like a datetime column since "YYYY-MM' dates can be compared lexicographically.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an alternative solution instead of `drop(['v1'], 1)`?

Comment: @ahbon Yes you can just select the columns you want to keep instead of deleting the column you want to drop.

Comment: @ahbon I edited my answer to address your comment but jezrael rolled it back because for some reason he does not want me to respond to your question. See [here instead](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/581cd87b-953a-4a0d-9572-d52f26339b81/view-source).

Comment: Both of your answers are awsome and helpful. Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can select columns in `loc` in list:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period('m')

df1 = (df.loc[df['date'].between('2017-03', '2017-05'), ['v2','v3']]
         .groupby(df['type'])
         .mean()
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  type         v2         v3
0    a  11.333333  22.666667
1    b  12.000000  24.000000
```

Or you can use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) for all columns without `v1`:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['v1'])
df1 = (df.loc[df['date'].between('2017-03', '2017-05'), cols]
        .groupby('type', as_index=False)
        .mean())

print (df1)
  type         v2         v3
0    a  11.333333  22.666667
1    b  12.000000  24.000000
```